# Average value of potential energy and kinetic energy in simple harmonic motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, waves, harmonic-oscillator

In the Derivation of the formula of average potential energy and kinetic energy in simple harmonic motion.
Please explain the step in the image.[image]

Comment: integrate the energy over one Period and divide by the length of the period.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The missing step is $sin^2(\omega t + \phi)={1 \over 2} (1-\cos(2(\omega t + \phi)))$

Comment: Thank you very much!